# Taking video from a DVD & Making it Editable

Tags: premiere, dvd

I'm fairly familiar with Adobe Premier... done a few small projects in it.  Recently my father-in-law gave me a corporate training video, on DVD, that was done for his company back in 2008.  The people that did the video are no longer available.  He asked me to make a few edits. I'm not sure how to extract the video from the DVD and import it into Premier.  When I look at the DVD in the finder (Mac OS), this is what I see...

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: VTS_01_1.VOB through VTS01_5.VOB is the video itself. It's in 5 files because the DVD spec requires the files be no larger than 1GiB. Try loading those files in Premiere.

Comment: Yeah that was the first thing I tried.  No luck.  Premier would not recognize the files.  I ended up spending $30 on some software to rip DVD's.  Worked great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up spending $30 to buy MacX DVD Ripper.  Worked great. Easily converted the video files on the DVD to an MP4 file, which loaded right into Premier.

Comment: Well, I'd suggest the next option would have been to download ffmpeg for Mac and remux the VOBs into a MPEG PS container. There's no recompression that way and it's much quicker.

Answer (score 2):

A musician family member who edited video on his Apple PowerBook G4, swore by Handbrake. Handbrake is now available cross platform OSX, Linux, and Windows (through Windows 10). Much this musician's work in later years was ripping and repackaging DVD footage - and what he particularly liked was that Handbrake was "bulletproof." It even ripped mini-DVD AVCHD video from my Panasonic hand-held, before we were calling it H.264. Downloads available here: [Handbrake Downloads](https://handbrake.fr/downloads.php)

Comment: Adapter is another free video encoding application. It's a GUI wrapper for ffmpeg.

Comment: Link to adapter: https://www.macroplant.com/adapter/download/mac/